# Поиск числа в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка с текстом, мне же нужно определить есть ли в ней не целое число, учитывая то что число может быть как с точкой, так и с запятой, например: `текст текст 0.19393` или `текст текст 0,2293738 текст`

Если есть не целое число - вывести его.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Если есть не целое число - вывести его.*

```
$str = 'текст текст 0.19393 или текст текст 0,2293738 текст';

! preg_match('~\d+[.,]\d+~', $str, $i) ?: print $i[0];
```

Выведет первое соответствующее шаблону число:

```
0.19393
```